# Getting the frequency of a 0.33Hz to 3Hz signal

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency

I read a noisy signal from an accelerometer which is attached to the pedal of a stationary bike and need to find the frequency of the signal/ speed of the person cycling. 
I taught of the following solutions and would like to know if I overlooked any or made some incorrect assumptions.

Currently the working solution is a low pass (10-30 point moving average) and then a peak detection with a minimum amplitude requirement and minimum time requirement. However this solution doesn't work very well when nearing 0.33Hz (20 RPM)

I tried using an fft but the result was never accurate enough for the small differences in frequency I am looking for.

I taught about using autocorrelation but how I understand it, I would have to wait atleast a period and then some before I could detect the frequency.

Any other ideas are welcome, or if anybody knows what is used in the commercial version it would be great to know.

Comment: If you know that the signal is band limited to 0.33 to 3 Hz, I would sample it at a rate of 10 Hz for 6.4 seconds and than use the furrier transform. If you are interested in getting a pick exactly at 0.33 Hz use a sampling rate of 10/1.1 and the third bin will provide you with the power in the 3.3 frequency.

Comment: Peak detection of two peaks also requires collecting at least "one period and then some", so why not use autocorrelation?

Comment: @Moti: I'll see what this give, however the signal is not band limited at those values, I just don't have to detect the frequency anymore when it is outside this range. However it is a really big downside that I have a delay of 6.4 seconds. Is there any way to get accurate information faster?

Comment: @hotpaw2 I detect both minima and maxima so I get can recalculate the frequency 2 times each period.

Comment: You can compute an autocorrelation every new sample, which is even more often, thus potentially with less latency, than waiting for just 2 times per period.

Comment: To detect 0.33 Hz in noisy environment is challenging. You need enough samples to get it and you need some time. You could compute the FFT with every sample (as suggested by you) but you are getting an estimate which is for the "middle" of the sampling period, The latency of 3 seconds or 1.5 seconds is hard to avoid. Sample for 3 seconds. at high frequency (based on the range of the noise). You may use an analog filter to band limit (low pass) the signal. Computing an FFT of 256 points every 10 milliseconds or even faster is not a challenge.

Comment: @Moti Thank you for the explanation! I got a working version by using a low pass and peak detection which works fine. I removed a lot of the noise by improving the hardware of my design so its much less of a problem. If I ever get the time I will continue trying to see if its better to use some kind of FFT.